# Include library function without function body

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.6.x

Using solc 0.5.0 it's possible to compile a contract that has a library function implemented with no body. For example:

```
library Hasher {
  function MiMCSponge(uint256 in_xL, uint256 in_xR) external pure returns (uint256 xL, uint256 xR);
}
```

However it seems this is no longer possible in solc 0.6.0 or 0.8.0. The reason for wanting to do this is that this Hasher library is compiled by circom to bytecode without the accompanying solidity code.

How can I solve this problem so I can consume the library without the function body?